# Alt text aren't detected

Tags: text, seo, blogger, alt

I've added alt texts to images showed in my blog (Blogger):

```
<img alt="lune insomniaque" height="424" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-2mKhLneD2QY/V0GeFfPnyuI/AAAAAAAAAAM/IJdyY4wmKoshK50OtSQW9eR_6fBCD1tXACLcB/s640/moon-1054721_1920.jpg" title="La lune, le quotidien des insomniaques" width="640" />
```

but when I'm using various SEO tools it says me that there are no alt texts. I've googled this but nothing found...

Comment: If you have added them and you can see them, what does it matter what 'seo tools' report ?

Comment: If seo tools can't read them maybe that google bots can't either...

Comment: Can you see them with your own eyes ? Third party 'seo' tools are not worth bothering about.

Comment: try www.feedthebot.com/tools/alt/

Answer (score 0):

To me looks like proper alt. Looks like some tools are useless.

Answer (score 0):

i think tool says you that there are no alt texts for some other images used in your blog

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and improve/extend your answer to meet the basic criteria, otherwise consider to delete it. Thank you!